# Does lang="en" refer to the file or the webpage?

Tags: html

What does my `lang="en"` declaration in the start tag actually mean? Is it saying ***the website is in english***, or is it saying that ***I am coding in English***?
I am currently coding in English (my classes and ids are english keywords, basically) but the website text is in a different language. My validator tells me I should say lang="en".... is that right?

Comment: The lang attribute indicates the language of page of the website. It is use for SEO and automatic translation AI.